# Single page application with Rails 4 and AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, single-page-application

Ok, this idea might seem quite a bit crazy and it kindo' is (at least for me at my level). 
I have a fairly standarad rails app (some content pages, a blog, a news block, some authentication). And I want to make it into a single page app.

What I want to accomplish is:

1. All the pages are fetched through `AJAX` like when using `turbolinks`, except that the AJAX returns only the `view part` (the yield part in the layout) withought the layout itself, which stays the same (less data in the responces, quicker render and load time).
2. The pages are mostly just static html with `AngularJS` markup so not much to process.
3. All the actual data is loaded separately through JSON and populated in the view.
4. Also the url and the page title get changed accordingly.

I've been thinking about this concept for quite a while and I just can't seem to come up with a solution. At this point I've got to some ideas on how this actualy might be done along with some problems I can't pass. Any ideas or solutions are greatly appreciated. Or might be I've just gone crazy and 3 small requests to load a page are worse then I big that needs all the rendering done on server side.

So, here's my idea and known problems.

1. When user  first visits the app, the view template with angular markup is rendered regularly and the second request comes from the `Angular Resource`.
2. Then on ngClick on any link that adress is sent to ngInclude of the content wrapper.

   1. How do I bind that onClick on any link and how can I exclude certain links from that bind (e.g. links to external authentication services)?
   2. How do I tell the server not to render the layout if the request is comming from Angular? I though about adding a parameter to the request, but there might be a better idea.
3. When ngInclude gets the requested template, it fires the ngInit functions of the controllers (usually a single one) in that template and gets the data from the server as JSON (along with the proper page title).
4. Angular populates the template with the received data, sets the browser url to the url of the link and sets the page title to what it just got.

   1. How do I change the page title and the page url? The title can be changed using jQuery, but is there a way through Angular itself?
   2. Again, I keep thinking about some kind of animation to make this change more fancy.
5. Profit!

So. What do you guys think?

Comment: I think that you need to spend some time learning Angular. This question does not make sense if you have done the basic tutorial. http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: @Emmentaler I've done that tutorial. But I don't want to duplicate all my routing in the Angular controller and leave the routing to the server. Also some of the templates need to be prerendered on the server side so I can't just move them to the public/templates/ directory and let angular pick them up by itself.

Comment: My opinion is that you're asking in the wrong place, try http://javascriptroom.com/ *(Too Localised)*

Comment: If you rendering on the server then Angular is not a good choice.  One of the main purposes of Angular is to give you the same benefits of templating and binding that you get in typical server environments (JSP, JSF, PHP) entirely on the client.  Personally I would not mix the two paradigms.

Comment: If it'sa  single page app... what does server routing have to do with anything? Routing in client is hash based. I agree with @Emmentaler. None of this question makes sense, it really doen't appear you have a good grasp of angular methodology.  As for page title try `document.title`

Comment: @Emmentaler, then why are there so many cases and apps using angular with rails? angularjs-rails gem has about 60 thousand downloads (not counting the direct download of source code from angular and installing the gem from github). None of it makes sense? Don't think so.

Comment: @charlietfl ok, it's not exactly a single-page app, I just don't really know how exactly to call it. The basic idea is that the layout(wich is the heaviest part of the page) gets rendered and sent to the user just once and then all the content is populated and manages through smaller and simpler Ajax requests.

Comment: Irregardless... you can have routing client side that has nothing to do with server side routing and will never conflict. Very hard to figure out what you are asking. While working on angular coding...turn off your rails mind completely and just think of server as a place to get data and template files from.

Comment: page titel is `document.title` in native javascript

Comment: @charlietfl ok, there is one very important question in there. Position 2.1

Comment: @charlietfl lets start in the first place. Do I even need explicit routing on the client side apart from the one built in the resources? Don't think so. So I can adress the links' href attribute and use it as a template path.

Comment: Maybe this blog post will help https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/how-to-integrate-angularjs-with-rails-4  but it is my opinion that you derive very little benefit from dynamic client binding and dynamic server binding.  Generally angular apps have a complete service layer that communicates with a REST service layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in case enyone ever finds this idea worth thinking about. 
The key can be solved as follows.

**Server-side decision of whether to render the view or not.**

Use a param in the `ngInclude` and set the `layout: false` in the controller if that param is present.
Have not found an easier way.

**Client-side binding all links except those that have a particular class no-ajax**
Here's a directive that does it.

```
App.directive('allClicks', function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var $a = element.find('a').not($('a.no-ajax')),
            fn = $parse(attrs['allLinks']);
        $a.on('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          scope.$apply(function() {
            var $this = angular.element(event.target);
            fn(scope, {
              $event: event,
              $href: $this.attr('href'),
              $link: $this
            });
          });
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

And then use it on some wrapper `div` or `body` tag like `<body ng-controller="WrapperCtrl" all-links="ajaxLink($href)">` and then in your content div do `<div id="content" ng-include="current_page_template">`

In your angular controller set the current_page template to the document.URL and implement that ajaxLink function.

```
$scope.ajaxLink = function(path) {
   $scope.current_page_template = path+"?nolayout=true";
}
```

And then when you get your JSON with your data from the server don't forget to use `history.pushState` to set the url line and `document.title =` to setr the title.